# Problem with Encoding in FileOpen and StringBuilder in i18n

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, stringbuilder

when I look at my file that I have saved with i18n, it is ok for example there is "Fïll Âll ülle~" in it which is what I want..but the way in the code I am trying to read the contects of this file and return it as a String is some thing like that:

```
        string sLine = String.Empty;
        StringBuilder sHTMLText = new StringBuilder();
        int nFileHandle = FileSystem.FreeFile();

        sHTMLText.Append(String.Empty);
        FileSystem.FileOpen(nFileHandle, sFileName, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Default, OpenShare.Default, -1);

        while (!FileSystem.EOF(nFileHandle))
        {
            sLine = FileSystem.LineInput(nFileHandle);
            sHTMLText.Append(sLine);
        };
        FileSystem.FileClose(nFileHandle);
        return sHTMLText.ToString();
```

but when I am debugging it, it is corrupting the correct translated stuff like  "Fïll Âll ülle~" and manipulating them, so I think my method is not doing it in a way that honors Encoding like I have set my computer Regional/Language Settings to French .... so How can I correct my existing code or write something similar that also cares about Encoding and the lang set on my computer?

Thsanks

Comment: StringBuilder (like String and most of the rest of the .NET Framework) strictly uses the "Unicode" encoding (a.k.a. UTF-16 little endian). You can usually avoid any encoding issues by strictly using some form of Unicode encoding throughout your project.

Comment: thanks, I did not know that...so the result might be different if I had wanted the Encoding.DEFAULT ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the system default encoding, then you have to specify that option. .NET presumes some type of Unicode will be used, if nothing else is specified. In most cases, UTF-8 will be used for files, but there are exceptions (such as when the file is prefixed with a Byte Order Mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx use a StreamReader with the correct encoding.

hth

Mario

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read a file that was saved in a non-Unicode encoding, then you must specify exactly what that encoding was when you open the file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\myfile.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
        {
            // read the file with the reader object.
        }

    }
}
```

Once you specify the encoding, then the file will automatically be translated into the internal string format (UTF-16 LE) when it is read. Note that the conversion of a valid file in a legacy character encoding into Unicode will always always succeed with no difficulties if the encoding is specified correctly. Saving a file in a legacy encoding is more problematic and requires that all of the source characters map to the legacy encoding or an appropriate fallback mechanism is in place.

Using Unicode exclusively throughout the system in the future will tend to make things easier going forward. Relying on the default system encoding to be set correctly creates a hidden configuration dependency that can cause problem during any migrations, distributed applications, and other circumstances.